# Getting error creating tables with ImprovedNamingStrategy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

my pojo looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
```

When I keep the name there, everything works, hibernate sql log:

```
 create table users (id int8 not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

When I remove the annotation, I get :

```
Hibernate: create table user (id int8 not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))
19:24:43 [localhost-startStop-23] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table user (id int8 not null, username varchar(255), primary key (id))
19:24:43 [localhost-startStop-23] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - ERROR: syntax error at or near "user" Position: 14
```

I am trying to use this, as it is defined in my xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

Any suggestions, why the namingstrategy isn't working?

Comment: Isn't user a reserved keyword ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default table name `USER` is a reserved keyword. In this case you have to specify `name` explicitly in order to add necessary escaping to it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`USER`")
public class User { ... }
```

Comment: With that setting, what would the table name be? Will it be USER with quotes?

Comment: @Jaanus: `USER` without quotes. Quotes tell Hibernate to apply necessary escaping in queries.

Comment: Are you sure it works, other poster said, that user is not allowed table name at all. Or the CAPS version would work?

Comment: Case doesn't matter. Documentation says: "As a general rule, if you get spurious parser errors for commands that contain any of the listed key words as an identifier you should try to quote the identifier to see if the problem goes away." `user` is a valid table name if quoted in queries.

Comment: So other answer is basically wrong, I CAN create table named `user` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

List of PostgreSQL keywords:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

> Labeled "reserved" are those tokens that are not allowed as column or
>   table names.

And your table name:

> USER  reserved

is in fact reserved.

So you cannot create table named `user` in PostgreSQL. That's why with annotation everything is OK as annotation specifies name `users`. There is no such keyword.